# Refresh Registration page after submitting

Tags: submit, refresh, registration

In my site, I have made a registration page named registration.php. When I submits it redirects to reg_success.php. But If i press back button after my succesful registration, then also the registration page i.e registration.php remains filled. I want that if my registration is complete and I press back on browser then my registration page should come blank.

Kindly help me, what code I need to add to the registration page on clicking back on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line of code :

```
 window.location.reload();
```

or also you can use following way :

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```